# Did the writers involved in “Warrior Nun Areala” ever write a conclusion to “The Angel and the Coming Storm?”

Tags: comics

I am going to give an explanation to those of you who have no idea what I am talking about.

“Warrior Nun Areala” is a comic book series that Ben Dunn started in 1994. It stars Shannon Masters, a nun who fights demons. It has four main volumes/series, as well as over a dozen spin-offs, crossovers, limited series and one-shots.

My question focuses on “Warrior Nun Areala, Volume 3.” This volume has 19 issues published between July 1999 and February 2001. The writers planned on making it into an ongoing series, but they cancelled it for one reason or another. “The Angel and the Coming Storm” is a story arc running from Issues #9-#12. In this arc, Sister Shannon finds out from Demon Princess Lillith that something very bad is going on in the Vatican. However, she had to defy the Vatican and break Lillith out to find out more. Shotgun Mary joins up with them to storm the Vatican. What is going on in the Vatican is that The Angel (that is, Satan) has been released and is preparing to launch a war. At the end of Issue #12, Sister Shannon puts her headgear back on and she, Mary and Lillith prepare to confront The Angel.

Now, at this point, you might think that this is going to be the ultimate showdown, right? Well, unfortunately, the readers never get to see it. Instead, Issues #13-#19 take place a few months later, Sister Shannon is missing in action, and it focuses on a new character named Sister Eleanore Angeli as she tries to protect New York City in Sister Shannon’s place. Nobody says anything about The Angel or Lillith, and Father Crowe strongly implies that Sister Shannon wound up in Hell. Shotgun Mary does show up alive and well, but she gives no hints about what happened.

In case you are curious, Sister Shannon comes back as the main character in “Warrior Nun Areala, Volume 4.” However, the story does not explain what happened to her or how she came back. Not only that, but it shows her working in the Vatican as though she had never defied it. I get the impression that the writer of that volume decided to reboot the series.

I have been looking around for information on what they intended to do with that story arc, but I have had little luck finding it. Did the writers ever write a conclusion to the “The Angel and the Coming Storm” story arc?

Comment: If this were a live action series, the obvious answer would be that the actress was busy during the third season and wasn't available to play her part. But for comic books, this excuse doesn't work.